C++17 copy elision rules and implicitly move
There is the following piece of code
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() {}

    // Explicit move constructor
     A(A&&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    // Copy constructor is deleted
    A(const A&) = delete;

    char x;
};
A a;
A foo() {
    A a;
    return a;  // Return by value, let the compiler apply move semantics
}
A bar() {
    
    return a;  // Return by value, let the compiler apply move semantics
}
int main() {
    A a = foo();  // Explicit move of the returned object
    A a2 = bar();
}

using the following arguments for compilation --std=c++17  -fno-elide-constructors
example
Inside foo since copy elision is disabled based on standard if x is move-eligible, the expression x is an rvalue.
Otherwise, it is an lvalue.
Based on this the move constructor is called .
For the bar the return value is a which has static storage.  For this, the move constructor is not implicitly called  . It is needed explicity use move. My question is why this difference based on if storage of variable a?

::a is not an r-value, so a copy must be returned. -fno-elide-constructors probably doesn't do what you want in C++17. You can check by replacing return a; with return std::move(a);

The A returned by A foo() isn't moved from at all. In practice it is allocated before the call is made and used inside the scope of foo. (And that way a copy is ellided)


My question is why this difference based on if storage of variable a?

Because it would be fatal if simply writing return a; in a function meant that a's state will be lost next time it is used. Imagine you have
std::vector<int> x;
std::vector<int> f() { return x; }

would then want that x will become empty each time f is called?
The only reason that it makes sense to automatically move local variables with automatic storage duration is that we know that they can't be used anymore once the function exits.
